# Is it possible to broadcast a Custom Event?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a setup like the one below, where all three elements inside body are subscribed to some event ([relevant code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXVwvb?editors=1010)):

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var span = document.querySelector('span');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
    
div.addEventListener('ding', function() {
  console.log('click');
});
    
span.addEventListener('ding', function() {
  console.log('clack');
});
    
button.addEventListener('ding', function() {
  console.log('bang');
});
    
document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ding')); // ???
//  expected output: 'click clack bang'
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  <span></span>
  <button></button>
</body>
```

As far as I know, `CustomEvent` bubbles up and does not trickle down, which is probably what I need. Is there a possibility to dispatch a `CustomEvent` so that all three handlers would fire?

Comment: The content of your question goes **in** your question, not just linked.

Comment: Why do you want to use events like that?

Comment: @Ionut, broadcasting app-wide events from separate parts. Such as a log-in form telling others that the user has logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to fire the event individually on each of the three elements. However, you can use `addEventListener()` on your `document.body` in order to make it fire these events for each of the elements when `document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ding'));` is called.

Example:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var span = document.querySelector('span');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

div.addEventListener('ding', function() {
  console.log('click');
});

span.addEventListener('ding', function() {
  console.log('clack');
});

button.addEventListener('ding', function() {
  console.log('bang');
});

document.body.addEventListener('ding', function() {
  div.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ding'));
  span.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ding'));
  button.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ding'));
});

document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ding'));
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  <span></span>
  <button></button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to fire it on each of the three elements individually. As you say, the path is from the element *up* the hierarchy to the root; even the capturing phase (which we mostly don't use anymore) only goes down to the target element and no further.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you will have to fire it on each elements... I think you could write a wrapper which remember elements you want to add a listener on. Then you need a method to boradcast the event... You can write everything in a module :

```js
var EventManager = (function(){
 var events = {};

 return {
       addEventListener : function (element, eventId, callback){
         // check if you already have this event
            if (!events[eventId])
               events[eventId] = [];
        
            // add the listener
            element.addEventListener(eventId, callback);
      
            // remember the element
            events[eventId].push(element);
       },
    
       dispatch: function(eventId){
          if (!events[eventId])
            return;
        
          // get every element where you want to dispatch the event
          events[eventId].forEach(function(element){
             element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventId));
          })
      }
  }
})()
```

I didnt test it be it should do the work I think. You can add methods to remove listeners as well and maybe change a little bit of code to handle normal event like 'click' etc... Hope it helps

EDIT: a singleton may be better ;)